# What is ffmpeg, avcodec, x264?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, x264

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg), I read that

> FFmpeg is a free software project that produces libraries and programs
>   for handling multimedia data. The most notable parts of FFmpeg are
>   libavcodec, an audio/video codec library used by several other
>   projects, libavformat, an audio/video container mux and demux library,
>   and the ffmpeg command line program for transcoding multimedia files.

So ffmpeg is a wrapper of avcodec? And I often hear that people encode video with x264 using ffmpeg. So ffmpeg is also a wrapper of x264?

How are they related ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First of all, to clear up some terms:

- FFmpeg is a software project with lots of people involved, a Wiki, a bug tracker, some funding, etc.
- `ffmpeg` is one of the tools they offer (others are `ffplay` and `qt-faststart`, for example).
- [Libav](http://libav.org/) was fork of the FFmpeg project, which supplied the `avconv` binary. Some distributions decided to ship Libav instead of FFmpeg programs for some time, notably Ubuntu, which caused a bit of confusion in the transition period where the Libav command was still named `ffmpeg`. Current Ubuntu uses the "real" `ffmpeg` again.

The `ffmpeg` tool is, like you said, a command line wrapper for a number of libraries designed for handling multimedia content. These include:

- libavcodec, for [encoding and decoding](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html) of audio, video and subtitle bitstreams
- libavformat, for [muxing and demuxing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) containers
- libavfilter, for applying [a variety of filters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) on audio, video and subtitles
- libswscale, which [scales images and video](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html) or [resamples audio](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html)
- libavresample, which was originally pushed to Libav and later integrated into FFmpeg. See [this thread](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-April/123746.html) for more about the history.

While the FFmpeg developers often provide their own encoders and decoders, you can enable third party libraries that have wrappers in libavcodec, in order to "glue" together FFmpeg and, say, [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html), which is the most popular H.264 encoder. This is often done when there's simply no point in "reinventing the wheel", which would be the case if one decided to write a new H.264 encoder with the goal to be better than x264. In other cases, some libraries may not be shipped with an `ffmpeg` build due to licensing reasons, such as libfaac—in that case, `ffmpeg` offers a native AAC encoder.

Common external encoders include:

- libx264
- libvpx (for VP8 and VP9 video)
- libfaac, libfdk-aac, libvo-aacenc for AAC audio
- libmp3lame
- libvorbis
- libxvid

For all of those you will find the wrappers under libavcodec, e.g. for libx264, [the file `libx264.c`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/libx264.c) provides the necessary code to push the video from the FFmpeg-internal format to the x264 encoder, and then pass that on to libavformat to write it into a file. The actual encoding is done through libx264.

As mentioned before, other encoders such as [the one for MPEG-4](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/mpeg4videoenc.c) are native to FFmpeg and do not rely on external libraries at all.

Finally, [there are several programs](http://ffmpeg.org/projects.html) that make use of FFmpeg tools and libraries, be it by providing an `ffmpeg` executable, or by picking parts of the libavcodec and libavformat libraries. This is allowed per the license and makes FFmpeg the most popular collection of multimedia tools today.

Comment: is h263 codec part of ffmpeg ?

Comment: FFmpeg's H.263 codecs are native, yes.

Comment: Maybe mention that native AAC enc is now stable.

Comment: @Mulvya Good point, missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand. I'm using Accord.NET to encode mp4's with H.264 and AAC and Accord.NET uses ffmpeg. But ti sounds like you're saying ffmpeg doesn't encode with H.264 by itself. Does that mean Accord.NET must be using libx264?

Comment: @KyleDelaney In short, yes. Although I don't know Accord.NET, but there are basically no alternatives to encoding H.264 with free, open-source tools.

Comment: Thank you. That's too bad, because according to FFmpeg's website I can't use it under LGPL if there are GPL libraries involved like libx264.